# Create Document with empty figures on purpose

Tags: graphics, formatting

In order to have my document checked for spelling errors, grammar mistakes and general consistency, I want to print it with empty dummy figures as placeholders of exactly the same size. The general layout shall stay the same. This is also done in order to save resources (i.e. money) when printing and because I am quite happy with my graphics and see most room for improvements in the text, rather than in the graphics.

The document consists of several *.tex files, which are all included in one masterfile. Is there an easy way of achieving this without having to change things (manually) within all the different files?

Comment: In your `documentclass` you can add the option `[draft]`, which should do the trick.

Comment: @Gilean0709 Thanks! Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks/Danke. Been here for a while,  I just registered now because I couldn't find an existing question for this problem.

Comment: @Nras: Nice that you have considered to subscribe to the `dark side` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the `draft` option in your documentclass, it doesn't include the images themselves, but only a frame of the same size as the image should be. Furthermore it also shows overfull hboxes by a vertical bar in the margin.